# Python - rounding to the nearest integer

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I've been trying to figure this out for ages but with no luck. I need to round each coefficient to the nearest integer.

To do this I introduce a small number dq=0.0001. If a[0]=0.5, then round(a[0]) = 0.0; this is clearly not good. However, to work around this introduce dq: round(a[0]+dq) = round(0.5001) = 1.0; this is good.

For negatives such as a[2] = -0.5: round(a[2]-dq) = round(-0.5001) = -1.0. I take into account the negatives using if statements. This is my code which does not return the right value:

```
a= 0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5
dq = 0.0001 #small number

b = round(a[0]+dq), round(a[1]+dq), round(a[2]+dq), round(a[3]+dq)

if a[0] < 0:
    b[0] == round(a[0]-dq)
if a[1] < 0:
    b[1] == round(a[1]-dq)
if a[2] < 0:
    b[2] == round(a[2]-dq)
if a[3] < 0:
    b[3] == round(a[3]-dq)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
(1,1,0,0)
```

Clearly it is the if statements that are dysfunctional.

P.s. and I need to be able to use the resulting b in later calculations.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could just use something like

```
a = [0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5]
print(list(map(lambda v: int(round(v + (dq if v > 0 else -dq))), a)))
```

this yields

```
[1, 1, -1, -1]
```

However, an alternative would be:

```
x = 0.49999 #just slightly less than 0.5
round(x)
>>> 0.0

#first round to 2 digits and then to an "integer"
round(round(x, 2))
>>> 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have never thought of using that second line of code with the lambda v. You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it in a smarter way, but here's a quick solution to your problem. First of all, use a `for` loop to round the elements of `a`. `a` is a tuple, by the way, so you could loop through its elements.

Second of all, your logic is at fault above. If an element of `a` is positive, i.e. `> 0`, you should add the `dq` instead of subtracting, as you mentioned yourself.

```
In [53]: for i in a:
    ...:     if i < 0:
    ...:         print(round(i-dq))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print(round(i+dq))
    ...:         
    ...:         
1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you'd like negative numbers to be rounded down to the nearest integer and positive numbers to be rounded up to the nearest integer. If that's the case, you could use `math.ceil` and `math.floor`:

```
import math

def my_round(x):
    if x < 0:
        return math.floor(x)
    if x >= 0:
        return math.ceil(x)


my_round(0.5) # 1
my_round(-0.5) # -1
```